# build binary on one distribution to run on other distribution

Tags: glibc

I want build a quite simple command line client application on a docker container to provide that application to customers. The application uses a CAN to USB adapter from PEAK (company building this adapter). PEAK provides a library (libpcanbasic), that the application is using to access the CAN bus.

In order to build the libpcanbasic library, the driver for the adapter must be installed. I use a staged docker container, where I first build the libpcanbasic.so library. I use then a second stage to have a container with a more recent GCC (gcc:12.1.0-bullseye).

No, I run into trouble, linking my application. The libpcanbasic.so depends on a libc version/flavor that is not part of the second stage container:

```
# readelf -d /usr/lib/libpcanbasic.so

Dynamic section at offset 0x189b8 contains 25 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.musl-aarch64.so.1]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libpcanbasic.so]
 0x000000007ffffffd (AUXILIARY)          Auxiliary library: [visibility=hidden]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x3f38
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x121f0
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x28998
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       16 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x289a8
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       16 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x190
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x1638
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x558
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              2719 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x28b88
 0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           3096 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
 0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0x3320
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x20d8
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             4680 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000018 (BIND_NOW)           
 0x000000006ffffffb (FLAGS_1)            Flags: NOW
 0x000000006ffffff9 (RELACOUNT)          185
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0
```

I can copy that libc file (libc.musl-aarch64.so.1) over to `/lib` in the second stage container and then linking would be fine:

```
# readelf -d ./build/client/bootloader_client 

    Dynamic section at offset 0x14da8 contains 29 entries:
      Tag        Type                         Name/Value
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpcanbasic.so]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
     0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
     0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x402d98
     0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x40e670
     0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x424d78
     0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       16 (bytes)
     0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x424d88
     0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
     0x0000000000000004 (HASH)               0x400278
     0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x4005d0
     0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x4010d0
     0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x400620
     0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              4274 (bytes)
     0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
     0x0000000000000015 (DEBUG)              0x0
     0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x424fe8
     0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           2448 (bytes)
     0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
     0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0x402408
     0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x402318
     0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             240 (bytes)
     0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
     0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x402268
     0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         3
     0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x402182
     0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0
```

But I guess, I would then get problems when I try to execute the resulting binary somewhere else.

Why isn't the application and the shared object (libpcanbasic.so) just depending on `libc.so`? Why the very specific version? Can this be changed? And, what is best practice, if I want to provide binaries for customers?

best regards,
Torsten

Comment: `ldd` tells you what running the program will use in the current environment. Can you edit into the question what the output of `readelf -d FILENAME` to see what is actually being requested?

Comment: Thanks, changed the way to determine the dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your library ends up not “just depending on `libc.so`” because it’s built using [musl libc](https://musl.libc.org/) (I’m guessing your first stage uses an Alpine-based container image). Your application doesn’t depend on `libc.so` either, it depends on `libc.so.6` which is [the GNU C library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (it was built on Debian, which defaults to the GNU C library).

Since you’re used to container builds, the best practice to provide binaries to costumers is to build them using container images corresponding to the targets you want to support. Since your library doesn’t have any particular dependencies as far as I can see, you can simplify your maintenance burden by building it using an older GNU C library-based distribution (to build a library usable on any distribution with the same library version or later), and a musl-based distribution if you want to support musl-based targets.

If you continue doing multi-stage builds, you should at least ensure that all your stages are based on the same image (or compatible images).

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. So I would have to provide n * m version. With n being the platform (x86, ARM) etc. and m the number of usual C libraries (must libc, glibc...). Is there a common lowest dominitor over all C libraries, that one could use?

Comment: There’s no common denominator, because the names of the `.so`s required by the resulting binaries are different (`libc.musl-aarch64.so.1`, `libc.so.6`); thus even if the C libraries were compatible, your library wouldn’t be easily usable with all of them. You could try avoiding any dependency on the C library, but that’s not always feasible.

Comment: I linked the libpcanbasic.so without libc (which works, because, I think the linker will left the required symbols open (malloc etc.)), but when linking the application, it fails: `/usr/bin/ld: bootloader_client: hidden symbol `atexit' in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a(atexit.oS) is referenced by DSO`

Comment: Yes, not linking against `libc` isn’t going to work with different C libraries unless the library doesn’t actually have any dependencies on it. It might be possible to produce a working “static” dynamic library.